# Problems with frame interpolation in Poser 9

Tags: animation

So I am making an animation in Poser 9. I am have a keyframe at the beginning of the animation and at the end of the animation for the feet. The feet literally have the same values at the end and beginning. For some reason poser decides to make the feet go all over the place and then back to normal between the start and finish even though the feet should not move. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in 3D animation if this happens you have what is referred to as gimble lock. You can fix this by adding keyframes in between and tweaking them slightly. If that doesn't work, try rotating one of the axis 360, as 0 and 360, 720 etc degree rotation on an axis are all the same position.

Here is a youtube vid that [demonstrates gimble lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrUCBOlJdt4)